# PYTHON What am i doing wrong? Loops and if statement

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
methods = ["SNMP", "SUDP","ESSYN", "SSYN", "HTTP"]

print("Methods: {}".format(', '.join(methods)))
method = input("Enter method: ")
method = method.upper()

while method != methods:
    print("ERROR: Method unknown")
    method = input("Enter method: ")
    method = method.upper()

if method in methods:
    print("Method: {}".format(method))

print(""
      ""
      "")

seconds = input("Enter length in seconds: ")
    print("{} seconds".format(seconds))
```

as you can see I'm trying to get an answer from the user then show the answer and go on to the next task. But if the answer is not on the list of methods, I want it to ask the question again. But I can't figure out how. The code that I use now is giving me the error message "ERROR: Method unknown" and when it finally does say: Method (with the method here) it won't go to the next task. Can anyone tell me what to do or what's wrong in this code?

Comment: is your indentation in your code exactly the same as it is here?

Comment: `method != methods` is not doing what you think it is - try `method not in methods`

Comment: Please fix your indentation so it's clear what the actual problem is.

Comment: The indentation is diffrent in my own code, But it has already been fixed by using not in instead of !=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How could

```
while method != methods:
```

ever make sense?

Perhaps you want:

```
while method not in methods:
```

Comment: How would that correct the issue?

Comment: Well thanks i just started. It worked but i didnt know how to do it with variables.

Comment: @JonClements -- How would it correct the issue?  Uh, "immediately"? "Expeditiously"?

Comment: Ahh... might have mis-read it... in that case the now `if method in methods` becomes redundant... (not my downvote by the way)

Comment: I think it was difficult to understand due to the poor formatting of the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
methods = ["SNMP", "SUDP","ESSYN", "SSYN", "HTTP"]

print("Methods: {}".format(', '.join(methods)))
ans = None
while ans is None: # when ans is set as method or any other value loop will stop asking for methods
    method = input("Enter method: ")
    if method.upper() in methods:
        ans = method  # when you set ans it will not ask again
        print("Method: {}".format(method))
        # rest of code here.... even another while loop for your input
    else:
        print("ERROR: Method unknown")
```

Comment: Look at the linked duplicate - there's no need for initial values here and checking against it - proper use of `continue` or `break` are more than suitable.